# Rails association in where - why aren't classes checked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

Suppose I have a rails application with a model for `User`s and another for `Account`s. There is a many-to-many association between users and accounts (sake of argument) and there is an association model `UserAccount` for this.

If I want to check whether User 1 is an owner of Account 1, I can do the query:

```
UserAccount.exists?(user_id: 1, account_id: 1)
```

On the other hand, I could do:

```
user = User.find(1)
acc = Account.find(1)
UserAccount.exists?(user: user, account: acc)
```

I had previously assumed that these were equivalent, **except** that form (2) would check the classes of the association. For example, if I had done:

```
UserAccount.exists?(user: acc, account: acc)
```

I would have expected to get an error, since `acc` is an `Account`, and not a `User`. Rails knows this, because it infers the class of the association from the column.

To my dismay, I just tried (an equivalent of) the above and I now think that rails does no class checks at all when querying associations in this way. Therefore I have two questions:

- Is this explicitly documented? I read this article: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html and found nothing relevant.
- Is there any way to *gain* this functionality? I would really like some kind of check when making this sort of query.

EDIT: I should note that this behaviour is basically inconsistent with the type checking that Rails *does* do in other circumstances. For example, the following snippet raises a type error:

```
irb(main):021:0> User.update(account: NotAnAccount.new)
  User Load (3.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
   (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):21
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Account(#47453450812560) expected, got #<NotAnAccount ... > which is an instance of NotAnAccount(#47453450812561)
```

Comment: Ruby is not a typed language -- there is no type checking.  What is happening (and you can confirm by looking at the SQL query generated) is that ActiveRecord is grabbing the id property from whatever object you stick in an as a parameter THEN doing a query against the user_accounts table.  As long as the id exists in the table the query will be successful.

Comment: @dbugger While you are right that Ruby is not strongly typed, I disagree that there is no type checking (particularly in Rails). For example, if I wrote "user.account = user" I would get an exception "AssociationTypeMismatch". I had forgotten this at the timing of writing, but I will add it to my question.

It is indeed clear how the SQL is generated, my question is "why is there this dangerous inconsistency", and "can I work around it".

Comment: With untyped languages, unit tests are a necessity. With great flexibility that ruby offers comes great responsibility.  `exists?`  is an extremely flexible query method that attempts to do what it thinks you want it to do, so you have to make sure you call it correctly.  There is nothing in the language to keep you from shooting yourself in the foot.